# Swapping 2 pointers x86 intel Assembly

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86

I am trying to swap 2 pointers in that are passed by reference to a sub-routine.  Here is what I have:

```
.data
    firstInputPrompt                BYTE 'Enter First String: ',0
    secondInputPrompt               BYTE 'Enter Second String: ',0

    firstString                     BYTE 16 DUP(0)              ;string buffers
    secondString                    BYTE 16 DUP(0)

    firstPointer                    DWORD OFFSET firstString    ;pointers
    secondPointer                   DWORD OFFSET secondString

.code

compare PROC

    push        ebp                 ;readying stack for use
    mov         ebp, esp

    push        eax                 ;used for comparing chars
    push        ebx                 
    push        ecx                 

    mov         ebx, [ebp+12]       ;ebx now a pointer to firstString
    mov         ecx, [ebp+8]        ;ecx now a pointer to secondString
    mov         ebx, [ebx]
    mov         ecx, [ecx]


;iterate over strings
iterate:    
    mov         al, [ebx]           ;compare characters
    cmp         al, [ecx]
    ja          swap_pointers
    jb          end_method

    mov         al, [ebx]
    cmp         al, 0
    je          end_method
    mov         al, [ecx]
    cmp         al, 0
    je          end_method  

    inc         ebx
    inc         ecx 

    jmp         iterate

swap_pointers:
    ;mov            ecx, [ebp+12]       ;get pointers again
    ;mov            ebx, [ebp+8]


    lea         ebx, dword ptr [ebp+12]
    lea         ecx, dword ptr [ebp+8]



end_method:
    ;pop used registers
    pop         ecx
    pop         ebx
    pop         eax
    pop         ebp
    ret
compare ENDP
```

The point where I get confused is right after the swap_pointers: label.  I can't figure out how to swap the 2 pointers.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Also, I pass the 2 pointers by reference on the stack before I call the sub-routine.

Comment: Is it your intent that when this code finishes executing that the contents of the memory labeled "firstPointer" is pointing to "secondString" and "secondPointer" is pointing to "firstString"?

Comment: Yes STLDeveloper, that is exactly the intent

Comment: So, could you just swap the pointer values?

Comment: That's what I am trying to do , I have tried many different ways, and there must be something I'm not understanding as the pointers don't seem to swap even if I mov ecx, [ebp+8] then mov ebx, [ebp+12]

Comment: So, that doesn't make sense.  Are you sure that what's at ebp+8 and ebp+12 are the correct starting values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
;load registers with pointers 
mov ebx, firstPointer
mov ecx, secondPointer
;save pointers from register, swapping content
mov firstPointer, ecx
mov secondPointer, ebx
;finis
```

Comment: Wow... That worked perfectly.  Thank you so much.. I can't believe I didn't try that... Must have been over thinking it.

Comment: No worries.  Assembler can make anyone a little nuts!

Answer (score -2):

xor swaps register values whenever required

```
 load registers with pointers 
 mov ebx, firstPointer
 mov ecx, secondPointer

 xor ebx,ecx
 xor ecx ebx
 xor ebx,ecx
```

gl

Comment: This is useless. It swaps the registers but not the pointer values in memory, so it actually does nothing. Besides, XOR-swap is slow, confusing and unnecessary. `xchg` instruction is much better if you actually wanted to swap the registers.